# Particular Solutions to Time Independent Nonhomogeneous PDE's in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates

I find myself working with PDE's like:
$$\nabla^2f = G$$
or
$$\nabla^2 f + k^2f = G$$

in spherical coordinates.

I know that the homogeneous form of these equations (Laplace's and Helmholtz) have well known solutions.  However, I do not know what method I could use to solve for the particular solution in each case.

Generally, the forcing function $G$ comes the previous step of a perturbation expansion, so many times it's expressed as an infinite sum, or something similar.

Is there a general method that can help me find the particular solution to these type of problems?

Comment: Do you know what a Green's functions is?

Comment: I have an idea, ut they were never introduced to me very well, and never as something that could be used to solve the PDE.  If there's  a method to solve these using Green's functions I'd be happy to learn!

Comment: Furthermore do you know the basics of Fouriertransform?

Comment: @tired Yes, I do know how to work with Fourier transforms.

Comment: ok http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4557.pdf ,you may like this!

Comment: @tired Thanks for the reference! Seems promising.  I'll look at it carefully after I get off work..  In the meantime, would you consider making ths an answer? (with maybe the most important points of the paper)

Comment: I think mazbe tomorrow i could do so, today i am a little bit too busy :/